# API search help JSON/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, api

First i'm new to Json and php. so i'm sorry if my question is too simple.

Alright, so i am using a movies JSON API and everything is good except one thing,

The url request for the search query is : `/api/movies.json?search='then the search here'` so i did in the `file_get_content('/api/movies.json?search='.$search_movie);`

I'm trying to add a search input and a button once it pressed it will change the `search_movie` variable to whats inside the input and refresh the page.

How can i do that or is there any better way to do it ?

Comment: I recommend you to use http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ that is an Http Client to make exactly what you want but easily, just include to your project and use it o maybe try http://phphttpclient.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also recommend using guzzle to do this. It is extremely easy to use and if you ever want more advanced functionality it will be available to you.

Here is a nice article describing step by step how to get started: http://www.sitepoint.com/guzzle-php-http-client/.